# Spring Batch JdbcCursorItemReader moving cursor backward

Tags: spring-batch

In spring batch `JdbcCursorItemReader` is `ResultSet` processing is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

In my case, I need to point the cursor to 1 row back, hence I want to set `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`, so that I can go back.

Any idea how to do it in spring batch or some workaround?

```
<bean id="databaseItemReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql"
            value="select * from document udd, field uff where uff.docid = udd.docid AND uff.field_name IN ('address','contractNb','city','locale','login','mobile','name','phone') ORDER BY udd.docid, uff.field_name ASC" />
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.migration.springbatch.UDocumentResultRowMapper" />
        </property>
        <property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="false"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

The contract of an `ItemReader` in Spring Batch is forward only, and the `JdbcCursorItemReader` is implemented according to this contract (Hence the `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`). So it is not possible to rewind the cursor back once it is opened.

That said, when the underlying resource is transactional (such as a database or a JMS queue) then calling read may return the same logical item on subsequent calls in a rollback scenario.

Please find more details in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#itemReader